# Flood fill using SkiaSharp

Tags: winforms, skiasharp

I am working on an app where users can add one (or more) images from a pre-determined collection. Each of these "base" images uses the same color to denote areas where the user can change the color.

Basically - I have images that contain an area that I want to be able to change the color of - using something similar to a "flood fill" functionality.

Right now I am using the following:

```
        var targetColor = color;

        var tableRed = new byte[256];
        var tableGreen = new byte[256];
        var tableBlue = new byte[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            tableRed[i] = targetColor.Red;
            tableGreen[i] = targetColor.Green;
            tableBlue[i] = targetColor.Blue;
        }

        paint.ColorFilter =
            SKColorFilter.CreateTable(null, tableRed, tableGreen, tableBlue);

        canvas.DrawBitmap(Image,new SKPoint( drawX, drawY), paint);
```

And while this "works" it doesn't do exactly what I want. This will recolor the whole object, instead of just the pixels I want

How would I go about doing this in SkiaSharp?

Im thinking that one option would be to go through and get each pixel of the specific color I used in the original image, and replace it with the new color.

What would that kind of code look like?
Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I went ahead and implemented this using the GetPixel() SetPixel() methods, though that seems like it could be more memory intensive than is optimal.

```
for (int y = 0; y < Image.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Image.Width; x++)
            {
                if (drawImage.GetPixel(x, y) == OriginalTincture.GetTinctureColor())
                {
                    drawImage.SetPixel(x, y, newColor.GetTinctureColor());
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I just need to deal with the fact that some of these images have pixels that are using a slightly different shade of the color I want to replace